# Is an OS kernel a singleton?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, linux

In my understanding, a singleton design pattern is where we have only one instance of an object in a system.

I am not sure on this part of the definition, but I believe in an OS there is only one running kernel at the supervisor mode.

Thus, is it correct to say that an OS kernel is an example of a singleton?

Comment: Your understanding of a Singleton is slightly off. When you use a Singleton, then you state in your design "there is only one of this *and there can never be more than one*". See the answer of @Berin how that last part doesn't apply to an OS kernel.

Answer (score 10):

No.  A Singleton is pattern for object oriented programming.  Most operating systems are not designed that way.  In fact, very few operating systems use object oriented programming at all within the kernel.  Linux is is known for consciously not using C++ (object oriented) and sticking with C (procedural).

Even if you were thinking of an operating system kernel as only one of something, where you would only want one, the whole concept of virtualization then turns that on it's ear.  Virtual machines host other kernels within the same hardware.  Then when you talk about containerization, you have other kernels hosted within your operating system.

To be honest, a singleton as a pattern should be one of the least used patterns--even if you only want one of something in your application.  The static accessor can cause seemingly unrelated code to be coupled with each other indirectly using them.

---

When you stop to consider what a [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) really is, you'll find that the Singleton pattern is even further from the proper understanding.  The kernel provides many functions, but it is an API in and of itself.

The Kernel:

- Manages resources
- Schedules threads and execution times for processes
- Switches context for the currently running process
- Manages memory and controls where applications are loaded
- Manages I/O for all devices (disk, graphics, sound, etc.)

Many kernels define an API for device drivers (the code that actually sets registers and moves data to and from devices) and provides a consistent API for applications to use.  The net result is that your application doesn't have to be rewritten just because you got a new graphics card.

If you were to try and shoe-horn object oriented concepts into the world of a Kernel, better patterns would be *interface*, *adaptor*, and a few others.  But there is no one pattern that you can say represents a kernel because kernels are much more complex.

Comment: "A Singleton is pattern for object oriented programming." I'm not sure I'd agree it's "for object oriented programming." While it's certainly used there frequently, there's no reason a static `struct` and some functions to manipulate it couldn't be a singleton, too. It would be nice if you could post a reference to the coupling you mention. I'd be interested to read more about that.

Comment: @user1118321: "singleton" is a term precisely defined in [the GoF book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), which is definitely about OOP. It is a pattern for classes & objects. Just because in almost any program one can find parts which exists only once during the lifetime of the program does not mean these parts are implemented using the Singleton design pattern.

Comment: @DocBrown The ancient `hsearch` POSIX API is arguably implementing the singleton pattern in C - but of course, it's older than the pattern description.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: I think it is debatable if that API function should really be called "Singleton", especially because there is an explicit call to `hcreate` necessary to create the hash table. Maybe this could be called an "ancient predecessor" of the GoF Singleton pattern.

Comment: NOTE: even if we included C implementations of object oriented techniques (i.e. structs and associated methods), you still can't assume there will only ever be one OS on a machine.  Even Windows Server 2016 includes an Ubuntu instance for SSH support when that feature is turned on.  That gives you full Unix running alongside the Windows kernel on the same machine without VMs.  It might have fit the bill a long time ago, but those days are over.  An OS is no longer a singleton.

Answer (score 4):

The [singleton design pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) ensures that there is only one single object instance  of a class. So unless you develop a kernel class with an object oriented programming language, it is not a singleton.

However, the concept of [singleton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics)) is more general than just a design pattern: it is a set containing one and exactly one element.

According to this definition, if you consider the set of active states of executed code, an [os microkernel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel) could be considered as singleton because it has only one active state (virtual memory map, list of processes managed by the scheduler, etc...) at any moment in time. All other programmes or services may have more than one active state, if several processes run the same code.

Answer (score 3):

To me, Singleton in not that much a feature of the type itself, but rather the way it is used. When you are accessing your kernel as `IKernel::Instance()` then it is a Singleton. When you get it from caller as parameter of type `IKernel`, then it is not a Singleton, even when in fact you never have several kernel objects in your program.

As the other answer states, it is more about object-oriented code - it is a way to get *object*, which has both method implementations and internal state the methods should use. But if you have, for example, "OOP in C", which uses structures of function pointers as objects, you could have a "Singleton" `get_kernel()`, which returned you such object.